# C# SipManager Unregister work only with breakpoints

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, sip

I have created a sip application using native sip in Xamarin Android.
When I'm unregistering the account my sip server don't receive che unregistered message, but if I place a breakpoint on unregistered method the server receive the unregistered message.
 I noticed a error in my registrationListener in the same case **DATA_CONNECTION_LOST**.

***Method CloseLocalProfile***

```
public void CloseLocalProfile()
    {
        if (MainActivity.mSipManager == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {

            if (MainActivity.mSipProfile != null)
            {
                Log.Info("Unregistering profile", "Un registering profile ");
                MainActivity.mSipManager.Unregister(MainActivity.mSipProfile, null);

              Log.Info("Closing profile", "Closing current profile ");
                MainActivity.mSipManager.Close(MainActivity.mSipProfile.UriString);
                                   MainActivity.mSipManager.UnregisterFromRuntime();
                MainActivity.mSipProfile.UnregisterFromRuntime();
                if (MainActivity.mSipProfile != null)
                {
                    MainActivity.mSipManager = null;
                    MainActivity.mSipProfile = null;
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {

            Log.Debug("onDestroy", "Failed to close local profile.", ee.Message);

        }
    }
```

***Logout Method***

```
  private async Task DoLogout()
        {

            _sipPlatformManager.CloseLocalProfile();
//RESET user information
            await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("Login");
        }
```

Can someone help me?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could it be that your application closes the connection before the REGISTER request is actually sent? Try keeping the connection active until you receive the final response.

Comment: I receive the register response immediately, when I do login action.

Comment: I guess that's because you don't close the application/connection after you login, but you do when you logout. Use a packet sniffer (like wireshark) and check if, when you unregister, the REGISTER request is actually sent.

Comment: ...and the REGISTER response received

Comment: I receive the register request on my server, and I receive the response also in my registrationlistener on device. I used wireshark too but the problem occurs on unregister request.

Comment: To unregister you have to send a REGISTER request with expires=0, there is no specific unregister message. Check with wireshark if the REGISTER request used to unregister is sent and the response received.